# How to get YouTube's channel subscriber count in Google Sheet with IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I want to get the number of subscribers of a YouTube Channel into a Google Sheet without using the YouTube API.

I did some research and found some examples but I'm still stuck.

The input is a url like this:
https://www.youtube.com/@youtube

The output I want is: 39.1 million

In a Google Sheet I tried with IMPORTXML like these:

`=IMPORTXML($A1,"//meta[@property='og:description']/@content")`

and I can get the property of the page but as soon as I do the right XPath for the subscriber count (which works in the browser's console):

`=IMPORTXML($A1,"//*[@id=""subscriber-count""]")`

I always get an Error "Imported content is empty".

Looking at other examples in Stackoverflow I also found this:

`=QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"where Col1 starts with 'subscriberCountText:'",0)`

And I receive this output:

`subscriberCountText:{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"39.1 million subscribers"}}`

But can't extract "39.1 million" properly from that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since you're already getting the subscriber count from what you provided, you can use [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) to get the output that you want. Try the formula `=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"where Col1 starts with 'subscriberCountText:'"),"[0-9,.]+ million subscribers")`. That should give you this [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSX4Q.png), which is what I believe is the output that you want.

Comment: @Saddles thanks, it did work for a second and now I received this error: **Error
Could not fetch url: https://www.youtube.com/@youtube**

I'd rather use the IMPORTXML function but can't pass the "Empty content" error described above

Comment: I got the same message earlier when I tried `youtube.com/@youtube`. Have you tried `https://youtube.com/@youtube`?

Comment: @Saddles now it seems to work again. Is it possible to edit the regex to be more generic (what if a channel doesn't have "millions" of subscribers?)... let's say I want to have the number and the word after but not "subscribers"

Thanks for your help, I hate regular expressions :D

Comment: You may try the formula `=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A2)),"where Col1 starts with 'subscriberCountText:'"),"\.*label\"":\""(.*)\""")`. It works with your example, with this being a [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhRiT.png) of its output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)),"where Col1 starts with 'subscriberCountText:'"),"([0-9,.,\s,a-z]+)subscriber")
```

Result: 39.1 million

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=REGEXEXTRACT(CHOOSEROWS(QUERY(TOCOL(IMPORTDATA(A1),1),"where Col1 like '%subscriberCountText%'",),-1),".*(?:""|\\x22)(.*)(?:""|\\x22)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, to grab the subscriber count from a YouTube channel into a Google Sheet without using the API, you can tweak your approach a bit. Instead of IMPORTXML, try using REGEXEXTRACT. Here's an example formula you can use:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA($A1)),"where Col1 starts with 'subscriberCountText:'",0), "\d+(\.\d+)?")`

This formula extracts the number, including decimals, from the output you're getting. It uses REGEXEXTRACT to find any sequence of digits, with or without a decimal point. Give it a shot, and it should work for getting the subscriber count into your Google Sheet.